# In which agamas/Puranas the 10 mahavidyas are mentioned?

Tags: puranas, agamas, tantra

The 10 mahavidyas are-

1)kali-The ultimate form of Brahman

2)Tara-The Goddess as Guide and Protector

3)tripura sundari-The Goddess Who is "Beautiful in the Three Worlds

4)Bhuvaneshwari-The Goddess as World Mother, or Whose Body is the Cosmos

5)bhairavi-The Fierce Goddess

6)chhinnamasta -The self-decapitated Goddess[5]

7)dhumavati-the widow goddess

8)baglamukhi-The Goddess Who Paralyzes Enemies

9)Matangi-the Prime Minister of Lalit

a
10)kamala-the Lotus Goddess; the "Tantric lakshmi.

I want to know that which oldest agamas,Puranas or Itihasas mention the 10 dasha mahavidyas.In Wikipedia **Kinsley says that origin of 10 mahavidyas cannot be older than 12th century**,Is it true?If not then which scriptures mentions the 10 mahavidyas